# Golang regex to replace string

Tags: go

I am trying to create a regex to replace string from content read from file

```
control_plane_ignition = <<END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION
{"ignition":"igntext"}
END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION
```

my code to replace:

```
masterContent := `new-igncontent`
var workerRe = regexp.MustCompile(`END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION\s(.*)\sEND_OF_MASTER_IGNITION`)
s = workerRe.ReplaceAllString(string(teraformtfvarContent), string(masterContent))
```

Expected:

```
control_plane_ignition = <<END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION
new-igncontent
END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION
```

Actual:

```
control_plane_ignition = <<new-igncontent
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking it to do is to replace a string starting with `END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION` and ending with `END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION` with `masterContent`, so this is what you are getting.

If you were to include `END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION` on both sides of your replacement string, you would get the desired effect:

```golang
    control_plane_ignition := `<<END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION
{"ignition":"igntext"}
END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION`

    masterContent := `new-igncontent`
    workerRe := regexp.MustCompile(`END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION\n(.*)\nEND_OF_MASTER_IGNITION`)
    s := workerRe.ReplaceAllString(string(control_plane_ignition), 
           "END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION\n" + masterContent + "\nEND_OF_MASTER_IGNITION")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/abyZd4E2uIg

PS: Please note my small changes in the regex, it wasn't compiling the way you posted it.

Comment: That can be a workaround, I was wondering if it would be possible to replace group1 match from the regex with new content. Thanks for this suggestion now I am unblocked

Comment: Perhaps not with `ReplaceAllString`.

Answer (score 0):

When you search for `END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION\s(.*)\sEND_OF_MASTER_IGNITION`, that entire substring will get replaced. So to preserve some fragments of it, you can capture them and refer to them with backreferences like `${1}`<sup>1</sup>.

You should also search for `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`, otherwise you'll replace everything between the first start tag and the last end tag, which is not what you want.

For example like this

```
var workerRe = regexp.MustCompile(`(?s)(\bEND_OF_MASTER_IGNITION\s+)(.*?)(\s+END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION\b)`)

s = workerRe.ReplaceAllString(content, "${1}"+regexp.QuoteMeta(masterContent)+"${3}")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/X7Gm6ClFNPD

Output:

```
control_plane_ignition = <<END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION
new-igncontent
END_OF_MASTER_IGNITION
```

---

<sup>1</sup> caveat: due to peculiarities of the Go regex implementation, avoid using bare backreferences like `$1` and always write them like `${1}`. `$1` "binds" even to non-digits and in case of `$1new-...` can become `${1new}-...`.